# Difficulty compiling Mumps

Tags: compilation, fortran

I've been trying to compile Mumps as a linear solver for IPOPT following these instructions here. https://mdolab-pyoptsparse.readthedocs-hosted.com/en/latest/optimizers/IPOPT.html And then later using this script here https://github.com/OpenMDAO/build_pyoptsparse/

When I attempt to do so however I get error messages like this and I'm unsure if these files manage to compile. I've only started using linux and I don't have much experience with compiling. What am I doing wrong? Do I need to set up my compiler somehow?

```
make  all-am
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/rory/Documents/untitled folder/build_pyoptsparse.601acad7/ThirdParty-Mumps'
  CC       metis_adapter.lo
  F77      MUMPS/libseq/mpi.lo
  CC       MUMPS/libseq/mpic.lo
  PPF77    MUMPS/src/tools_common_mod.lo
  CC       MUMPS/libseq/elapse.lo
  PPF77    MUMPS/src/dmumps_comm_buffer.lo
  PPF77    MUMPS/src/dmumps_struc_def.lo
  PPF77    MUMPS/src/mumps_ooc_common.lo
  PPF77    MUMPS/src/mumps_static_mapping.lo
MUMPS/libseq/mpi.f:601:72:

         CALL MUMPS_COPY_LOGICAL( SENDBUF, RECVBUF, COUNT )
                                                                        1
Warning: Type mismatch in argument ‘s’ at (1); passed INTEGER(4) to LOGICAL(4) [-Wargument-mismatch]
MUMPS/libseq/mpi.f:603:72:

         CALL MUMPS_COPY_REAL( SENDBUF, RECVBUF, COUNT )
                                                                        1
Warning: Type mismatch in argument ‘s’ at (1); passed INTEGER(4) to REAL(4) [-Wargument-mismatch]
MUMPS/libseq/mpi.f:606:72:

         CALL MUMPS_COPY_DOUBLE_PRECISION( SENDBUF, RECVBUF, COUNT )
                                                                        1
Warning: Type mismatch in argument ‘s’ at (1); passed INTEGER(4) to REAL(8) [-Wargument-mismatch]
MUMPS/libseq/mpi.f:608:72:

         CALL MUMPS_COPY_COMPLEX( SENDBUF, RECVBUF, COUNT )
                                                                        1
Warning: Type mismatch in argument ‘s’ at (1); passed INTEGER(4) to COMPLEX(4) [-Wargument-mismatch]
MUMPS/libseq/mpi.f:610:72:

         CALL MUMPS_COPY_DOUBLE_COMPLEX( SENDBUF, RECVBUF, COUNT )
                                                                        1
Warning: Type mismatch in argument ‘s’ at (1); passed INTEGER(4) to COMPLEX(8) [-Wargument-mismatch]
MUMPS/libseq/mpi.f:612:72:

         CALL MUMPS_COPY_2DOUBLE_PRECISION( SENDBUF, RECVBUF, COUNT )
                                                                        1
Warning: Type mismatch in argument ‘s’ at (1); passed INTEGER(4) to REAL(8) [-Wargument-mismatch]
  PPF77    MUMPS/src/mumps_sol_es.lo
  PPF77    MUMPS/src/mumps_part9.lo
  CC       MUMPS/src/mumps_c.lo
  CC       MUMPS/src/mumps_common.lo
  CC       MUMPS/src/mumps_orderings.lo
  CC       MUMPS/src/mumps_io.lo
  CC       MUMPS/src/mumps_io_basic.lo
  CC       MUMPS/src/mumps_io_thread.lo
  CC       MUMPS/src/mumps_io_err.lo
  CC       MUMPS/src/mumps_size.lo
MUMPS/src/mumps_io_thread.c: In function ‘mumps_low_level_init_ooc_c_th’:
MUMPS/src/mumps_io_thread.c:345:82: warning: ‘Internal error: mumps_low_level_init_ooc_c_th should not to be called with strat_IO=’ directive writing 84 bytes into a region of size 64 [-Wformat-overflow=]
     sprintf(buf,"Internal error: mumps_low_level_init_ooc_c_th should not to be called with strat_IO=%d\n",*async);
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
MUMPS/src/mumps_io_thread.c:345:5: note: ‘sprintf’ output between 87 and 97 bytes into a destination of size 64
     sprintf(buf,"Internal error: mumps_low_level_init_ooc_c_th should not to be called with strat_IO=%d\n",*async);
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
MUMPS/src/mumps_io_thread.c:382:86: warning: ‘Internal error: mumps_low_level_init_ooc_c_th should not to be called with strat_IO=’ directive writing 84 bytes into a region of size 64 [-Wformat-overflow=]
         sprintf(buf,"Internal error: mumps_low_level_init_ooc_c_th should not to be called with strat_IO=%d\n",*async);
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
MUMPS/src/mumps_io_thread.c:382:9: note: ‘sprintf’ output between 87 and 97 bytes into a destination of size 64
         sprintf(buf,"Internal error: mumps_low_level_init_ooc_c_th should not to be called with strat_IO=%d\n",*async);
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  PPF77    MUMPS/src/dmumps_ooc_buffer.lo
  PPF77    MUMPS/src/dmumps_load.lo
  PPF77    MUMPS/src/dmumps_part7.lo
  PPF77    MUMPS/src/dmumps_ooc.lo
  PPF77    MUMPS/src/dmumps_part4.lo
  PPF77    MUMPS/src/dmumps_part3.lo
  PPF77    MUMPS/src/dmumps_part8.lo
  PPF77    MUMPS/src/dmumps_part2.lo
  PPF77    MUMPS/src/dmumps_part6.lo
MUMPS/src/dmumps_part2.F:4416:31:

          CALL DMUMPS_557(id%N, IPE(1), NV(1), IPS(1), NE(1),
                               1
Warning: Element of assumed-shaped or pointer array passed to array dummy argument ‘ipe’ at (1)
MUMPS/src/dmumps_part2.F:4426:25:

          CALL DMUMPS_201(NE(1), ND(1), id%INFOG(6), id%INFOG(5),
                         1
Warning: Element of assumed-shaped or pointer array passed to array dummy argument ‘ne’ at (1)
MUMPS/src/dmumps_part2.F:4463:36:

                CALL DMUMPS_97(id%N, FRERE(1), FILS(1),
                                    1
Warning: Element of assumed-shaped or pointer array passed to array dummy argument ‘frere’ at (1)
MUMPS/src/dmumps_part2.F:4475:33:

             CALL DMUMPS_97(id%N, FRERE(1), FILS(1), NFSIZ(1),
                                 1
Warning: Element of assumed-shaped or pointer array passed to array dummy argument ‘frere’ at (1)
MUMPS/src/dmumps_part6.F:3575:14:

      &        root%SCHUR_POINTER(1),
              1
Warning: Element of assumed-shaped or pointer array passed to array dummy argument ‘val_root’ at (1)
MUMPS/src/dmumps_part6.F:3615:14:

      &        root%RG2L_ROW(1), root%RG2L_COL(1), INVERT,
              1
Warning: Element of assumed-shaped or pointer array passed to array dummy argument ‘rg2l_row’ at (1)
MUMPS/src/dmumps_part2.F:2851:19:

      &        PERM,FLAG(1))
                   1
Warning: Element of assumed-shaped or pointer array passed to array dummy argument ‘posi’ at (1)
MUMPS/src/dmumps_part2.F:2854:19:

      &        PERM,FLAG(1))
                   1
Warning: Element of assumed-shaped or pointer array passed to array dummy argument ‘posi’ at (1)
MUMPS/src/dmumps_part8.F:545:36:

             CALL DMUMPS_535( MTYPE, id%ISOL_loc(1),
                                    1
Warning: Element of assumed-shaped or pointer array passed to array dummy argument ‘isol_loc’ at (1)
MUMPS/src/dmumps_part8.F:1224:36:

             CALL DMUMPS_535( MTYPE, id%ISOL_loc(1),
                                    1
Warning: Element of assumed-shaped or pointer array passed to array dummy argument ‘isol_loc’ at (1)
MUMPS/src/dmumps_part8.F:1756:32:

      &           id%MYID_NODES, id%PTLUST_S(1),
                                1
Warning: Element of assumed-shaped or pointer array passed to array dummy argument ‘ptrist’ at (1)
MUMPS/src/dmumps_part8.F:1764:32:

      &           id%MYID_NODES, id%PTLUST_S(1),
                                1
Warning: Element of assumed-shaped or pointer array passed to array dummy argument ‘ptrist’ at (1)
MUMPS/src/dmumps_part8.F:1796:23:

      &          MTYPE, RHS_MUMPS(IBEG), LD_RHS, NBRHS_EFF,
                       1
Warning: Element of assumed-shaped or pointer array passed to array dummy argument ‘rhs’ at (1)
MUMPS/src/dmumps_part8.F:1805:23:

      &          MTYPE, RHS_MUMPS(IBEG), LD_RHS, NBRHS_EFF,
                       1
Warning: Element of assumed-shaped or pointer array passed to array dummy argument ‘rhs’ at (1)
MUMPS/src/dmumps_part8.F:3753:13:

      &       root%IPIV(1), root%LPIV, MASTER_ROOT, MYID_NODES,
             1
Warning: Element of assumed-shaped or pointer array passed to array dummy argument ‘ipiv’ at (1)
MUMPS/src/dmumps_part8.F:2101:39:

         CALL DMUMPS_245(id%root, id%N, id%S(1), LA_PASSED,
                                       1
Warning: Element of assumed-shaped or pointer array passed to array dummy argument ‘a’ at (1)
MUMPS/src/dmumps_part8.F:2141:42:

            CALL DMUMPS_245(id%root, id%N, id%S(1), LA_PASSED,
                                          1
Warning: Element of assumed-shaped or pointer array passed to array dummy argument ‘a’ at (1)
MUMPS/src/dmumps_part8.F:2253:23:

      &          MTYPE, RHS_MUMPS(IBEG), LD_RHS, NBRHS_EFF,
                       1
Warning: Element of assumed-shaped or pointer array passed to array dummy argument ‘rhs’ at (1)
MUMPS/src/dmumps_part8.F:2264:16:

      &          RHS_MUMPS(IBEG), LD_RHS, NBRHS_EFF,
                1
Warning: Element of assumed-shaped or pointer array passed to array dummy argument ‘rhs’ at (1)
MUMPS/src/dmumps_part8.F:2277:23:

      &          MTYPE, RHS_MUMPS(IBEG), LD_RHS, NBRHS_EFF,
                       1
Warning: Element of assumed-shaped or pointer array passed to array dummy argument ‘rhs’ at (1)
MUMPS/src/dmumps_part8.F:2287:16:

      &          RHS_MUMPS(IBEG), LD_RHS, NBRHS_EFF,
                1
Warning: Element of assumed-shaped or pointer array passed to array dummy argument ‘rhs’ at (1)
MUMPS/src/dmumps_part8.F:2344:23:

      &          MTYPE, RHS_MUMPS(IBEG), LD_RHS, NBRHS_EFF,
                       1
Warning: Element of assumed-shaped or pointer array passed to array dummy argument ‘rhs’ at (1)
MUMPS/src/dmumps_part8.F:2707:49:

      &          JDUMMY, id%KEEP(1), id%KEEP8(1), id%PROCNODE_STEPS(1),
                                                 1
Warning: Element of assumed-shaped or pointer array passed to array dummy argument ‘procnode_steps’ at (1)
MUMPS/src/dmumps_part8.F:2715:16:

      &          id%PTLUST_S(1), id%KEEP(1), id%KEEP8(1),
                1
Warning: Element of assumed-shaped or pointer array passed to array dummy argument ‘ptrist’ at (1)
MUMPS/src/dmumps_part8.F:2726:42:

           CALL DMUMPS_245( id%root, id%N, id%S(1), LA_PASSED,
                                          1
Warning: Element of assumed-shaped or pointer array passed to array dummy argument ‘a’ at (1)
MUMPS/src/dmumps_part8.F:2772:48:

      &          JDUMMY, id%KEEP(1),id%KEEP8(1), id%PROCNODE_STEPS(1),
                                                1
Warning: Element of assumed-shaped or pointer array passed to array dummy argument ‘procnode_steps’ at (1)
MUMPS/src/dmumps_part8.F:2782:16:

      &          id%PTLUST_S(1), id%KEEP(1),id%KEEP8(1),
                1
Warning: Element of assumed-shaped or pointer array passed to array dummy argument ‘ptrist’ at (1)
MUMPS/src/dmumps_part3.F:6046:21:

      &               id%ELTVAR( IELTPTR ), id%A_ELT( RELTPTR ),
                     1
Warning: Element of assumed-shaped or pointer array passed to array dummy argument ‘eltvar’ at (1)
MUMPS/src/dmumps_part3.F:6064:17:

      &           id%ELTVAR(IELTPTR),
                 1
Warning: Element of assumed-shaped or pointer array passed to array dummy argument ‘elnodes’ at (1)
MUMPS/src/dmumps_part3.F:6072:17:

      &           id%ELTVAR(IELTPTR),
                 1
Warning: Element of assumed-shaped or pointer array passed to array dummy argument ‘elnodes’ at (1)
MUMPS/src/dmumps_part3.F:6104:17:

      &           id%ELTVAR(IELTPTR),
                 1
Warning: Element of assumed-shaped or pointer array passed to array dummy argument ‘elnodes’ at (1)
  PPF77    MUMPS/src/dmumps_part1.lo
  PPF77    MUMPS/src/dmumps_part5.lo
MUMPS/src/dmumps_part5.F:432:44:

                CALL DMUMPS_564(id%KEEP(38), id%PROCNODE(1),
                                            1
Warning: Element of assumed-shaped or pointer array passed to array dummy argument ‘procnode’ at (1)
MUMPS/src/dmumps_part5.F:439:44:

             CALL DMUMPS_537(id%N,id%NSLAVES,ICNTL(1),
                                            1
Warning: Element of assumed-shaped or pointer array passed to array dummy argument ‘icntl’ at (1)
MUMPS/src/dmumps_part5.F:1311:14:

      &        id%CANDIDATES(1,1), id%I_AM_CAND(1) )
              1
Warning: Element of assumed-shaped or pointer array passed to array dummy argument ‘candidates’ at (1)
MUMPS/src/dmumps_part5.F:1668:20:

      &        id%N, id%MAPPING(1),
                    1
Warning: Element of assumed-shaped or pointer array passed to array dummy argument ‘mapping’ at (1)
MUMPS/src/dmumps_part5.F:5128:8:

      &  id%DBLARR(1), KEEP(13), id%INTARR(1),
        1
Warning: Element of assumed-shaped or pointer array passed to array dummy argument ‘dblarr’ at (1)
  F77LD    libcoinmumps.la
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/rory/Documents/untitled folder/build_pyoptsparse.601acad7/ThirdParty-Mumps'
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/rory/Documents/untitled folder/build_pyoptsparse.601acad7/ThirdParty-Mumps'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/home/rory/ipopt/lib/pkgconfig'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/home/rory/ipopt/include/coin-or/mumps'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/home/rory/ipopt/lib'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 coinmumps.pc '/home/rory/ipopt/lib/pkgconfig'
 /bin/bash ./libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c   libcoinmumps.la '/home/rory/ipopt/lib'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 MUMPS/include/dmumps_c.h MUMPS/include/mumps_c_types.h MUMPS/libseq/mumps_mpi.h mumps_compat.h '/home/rory/ipopt/include/coin-or/mumps'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libcoinmumps.so.2.1.0 /home/rory/ipopt/lib/libcoinmumps.so.2.1.0
libtool: install: (cd /home/rory/ipopt/lib && { ln -s -f libcoinmumps.so.2.1.0 libcoinmumps.so.2 || { rm -f libcoinmumps.so.2 && ln -s libcoinmumps.so.2.1.0 libcoinmumps.so.2; }; })
libtool: install: (cd /home/rory/ipopt/lib && { ln -s -f libcoinmumps.so.2.1.0 libcoinmumps.so || { rm -f libcoinmumps.so && ln -s libcoinmumps.so.2.1.0 libcoinmumps.so; }; })
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libcoinmumps.lai /home/rory/ipopt/lib/libcoinmumps.la
libtool: finish: PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin:/sbin" ldconfig -n /home/rory/ipopt/lib
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Libraries have been installed in:
   /home/rory/ipopt/lib

If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries
in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and
specify the full pathname of the library, or use the '-LLIBDIR'
flag during linking and do at least one of the following:
   - add LIBDIR to the 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable
     during execution
   - add LIBDIR to the 'LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable
     during linking
   - use the '-Wl,-rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
   - have your system administrator add LIBDIR to '/etc/ld.so.conf'

See any operating system documentation about shared libraries for
more information, such as the ld(1) and ld.so(8) manual pages.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Those are only _Warnings_ not _errors_. The library has been installed under `/home/rory/ipopt/lib` and you need to make your linker aware of this unique library path. Read the last ~15 lines again (between the dashed lines).

Comment: @jack Ah ok thanks. One more question, it says to 'clean build' pyoptsparse. I'd previously cloned the repository for pyoptsparse and installed it with 'pip3 install .'. What is the meaning of 'clean build' here?